# How to remove Help Menu from Grafana

Tags: grafana

Does anyone know how to remove the Help Menu from Grafana, I want this icon not to appear in the Grafana console.

I'm using Grafana 10.1.5 OSS

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In your Grafana configuration file, there is a [help] section where you can disable this menu.

Depending on how you've deployed Grafana, you want to ensure that you update your configuration like below.

```
[help]
enabled = false
```

[Documentation reference](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-grafana/#help).